# 'D\node-backend\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js

I created a simple server with express and was using nodemon as a dev dependency. But when I try to exec "npm run dev" getting the following error:

```
PS D:\R&D\node-backend> npm run dev     

> backend@1.0.0 dev
> nodemon ./app.js

'D\node-backend\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:942
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:939:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:780:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.1.0
PS D:\R&D\node-backend>
```

I tried different solutions from the net and reinstalled nodejs but nothing seems to work. I think there's an issue with where npm is trying to find the package. You can check code [here](https://github.com/SuMiT788/node-tutorial).

Comment: i think there is some problem with the location of nodemon

Comment: @steve I tried by deleting node_modules and package-lock.json and installing packages again but it is still not working.

Comment: did you go to this file "D:\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js" and is it there

Comment: @steve No, there's no such directory

Comment: thats the problem

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem in my react project and i found the problem from the folder structure.
I have to change the name of the folder from:

Module 3 practice M1&2 ===> Module 3 practice M1 and 2

for me that "&" is what causing the error
Hope this works